# Reading a file of txt to be fed into an array

Tags: java

Here a user enters a list of 1's and 0's.... so an input would 10001010. However I want it to read from a text file... my text file input.txt also containes 10001010... need the coverDataArray array to be fed the same string from the console as from a file.

I tried Datainput stream however, it throws me the exception

'

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String data1="";
```

...

.....

```
           try{
            System.out.println("Enter the binary bits");

           data1 = in.next();


              for ( int i = 0; i < data1.length(); i++)
            {
                covertDataArray[i] = Byte.parseByte(data1.substring( i, i+1));
            }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `File` Object instead of `System.in` to Scanner constructor. Try it as shown below:

```
String fileName = "input.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
String s = "";
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    s = scanner.nextLine();
    // your code. You can also use scanner.next() to read word by word instead of nextLine()
}
```

Comment: what would i do after passing the scanner the file? put in to a string? how do u go about doing that

Comment: edited the answer to add the appropriate code for reading from a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Byte.parseByte(data1.substring( i, i+1));
```

Your exception is caused by the fact that you're going up to `length - 1`, then `length - 1 + 1`, which is `length`, which is goign to cause your `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. This can be seen on this line:

```
covertDataArray[i] = Byte.parseByte(data1.substring( i, i+1));
```

At one point, `i` is equal to `length-1`, or the last index in your `String`. You then attempt to access the next element, which doesn't exist.

And as for your file, you can pass a `File` object into the `Scanner`.

**Example**

Either..

```
File file = new File("yourfile.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: so what should i set length condition in the loop to? length() - 1 ?

Comment: No. Change it to use `charAt` instead of `substring`.

Comment: what would i do after passing the scanner the file? put in to a string? how do u go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Byte.parseByte as a methode of parsing binairy input, this doesn't really work as parseByte will try to take a numerical input and parse it into a number between -128 and 127. You should use a different method.

Comment: hmmm? are you sure? it works perfectly when i input the same string from Console

Comment: That was from memory so not completely sure.